# Create instance by interface in runtime

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is that possible to create instance of object only by interface in runtime?

```
interface IModel {
    name: string;
}


function createInstance() {
    return something to make instance 
}

console.log(createInstance()); // out: {name:null}
```

Comment: an interface can't be constructed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

its impossible because interface ist compiled to js

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
interface IModel {
    name: string | null;
}

function createInstance(name: string | null): IModel {
    return { name };
}

console.log(createInstance(null));
```

([code in playgound](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20IModel%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%20%7C%20null%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction%20createInstance(name%3A%20string%20%7C%20null)%3A%20IModel%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%20name%20%7D%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aconsole.log(createInstance(null))%3B))

Comment: no, I would like to build instace of object. I have only interface without specyfic content, And I would like to take this interface as a definition of object and build object. It looks like rewriting object to object with Object.assign but interface hasnt got a instance until im dont  implement thiem on some class and create this classes object, so my question is "Is that possible"

Comment: In javascript **everything** is an object, even `{}` is an object. So the code in my answer does indeed create an object. `Object.assign` will do return the exact same thing. I'm not sure what it is that you're after.

Comment: yes but in your code I  must know name of field before compiling, Im trying to generate object by any interface without hard coding

Comment: Interface have not any interpetation in js after compiling so now I think this is not possible

Comment: So you want to create an object which has specific keys (and values set to null) based on an interface?

Comment: it`s impossible because interface is`t compiled to js.